# How to solve group function is nested too deeply

Tags: nested, having-clause

I have a problem when using Having clause and got an error where it said:

> group function is nested too deeply

Basically I am trying to use CASE WHEN inside Having clause and there are multiple CASE WHEN inside the CASE WHEN again.

```
Having(SUM(CASE WHEN OUTLET_ACCOUNT_GROUP IN('7-Eleven','99 Speedmart','KK Mart','MyNews.Com')
                             THEN SUM(NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0))>=0.02
                             ELSE
                             SUM(CASE WHEN NVL(TURIN_SALES,0)<0 AND NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0)>0 THEN 
                                CASE WHEN NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0)>(NVL(TURIN_SALES,0)*-1) THEN
                                    NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0)+ NVL(TURIN_SALES,0) 
                                    ELSE 
                                    0 
                                    END   
                                WHEN NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0)<0 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(MAVEN_SALES,0)                                         
                              END ) >=0.02 )
```

Comment: This doesn't look like code that someone could run, since it starts in the middle of your query. Can you prepare an example on SQL Fiddle or similar?

Comment: hi @halfer, I solved it by breaking to two having clauses. Sorry to trouble you.